# elastic map reduce timing out java.io.IOException: Unexpected end of stream

Tags: java, hadoop, elastic-map-reduce

I am running MAP reduce job (Elastic map reduce EMR ) service.The job works fine for small data set but gives following exceptions for large data set (File size 400MB)

Running another job with same big input file works fine but.Why so?

```
Error: java.io.IOException: Unexpected end of stream pos=19520590 contentLength= 458603265
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem$NativeS3FsInputStream.read(NativeS3FileSystem.java:313)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.moveToNext(MapTask.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.next(MapTask.java:185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)

Error: java.io.IOException: Unexpected end of stream pos=222629174 contentLength= 458603265
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem$NativeS3FsInputStream.read(NativeS3FileSystem.java:313)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.moveToNext(MapTask.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.next(MapTask.java:185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)

Error: java.io.IOException: Unexpected end of stream pos=155898310 contentLength= 458603265
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem$NativeS3FsInputStream.read(NativeS3FileSystem.java:313)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.moveToNext(MapTask.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.next(MapTask.java:185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)

Error: java.io.IOException: Unexpected end of stream pos=88645447 contentLength= 458603265
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem$NativeS3FsInputStream.read(NativeS3FileSystem.java:313)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.moveToNext(MapTask.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.next(MapTask.java:185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)

Error: java.io.IOException: Unexpected end of stream pos=19520590 contentLength= 458603265
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem$NativeS3FsInputStream.read(NativeS3FileSystem.java:313)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.moveToNext(MapTask.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.next(MapTask.java:185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)

Error: java.io.IOException: Unexpected end of stream pos=291259038 contentLength= 458603265
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem$NativeS3FsInputStream.read(NativeS3FileSystem.java:313)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.moveToNext(MapTask.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.next(MapTask.java:185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)

Error: java.io.IOException: Unexpected end of stream pos=222629174 contentLength= 458603265
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem$NativeS3FsInputStream.read(NativeS3FileSystem.java:313)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.moveToNext(MapTask.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.next(MapTask.java:185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)

Error: java.io.IOException: Unexpected end of stream pos=155898310 contentLength= 458603265
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem$NativeS3FsInputStream.read(NativeS3FileSystem.java:313)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.moveToNext(MapTask.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.next(MapTask.java:185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)

Error: java.io.IOException: Unexpected end of stream pos=88645447 contentLength= 458603265
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem$NativeS3FsInputStream.read(NativeS3FileSystem.java:313)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.moveToNext(MapTask.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.next(MapTask.java:185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)

Error: java.io.IOException: Unexpected end of stream pos=19520590 contentLength= 458603265
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem$NativeS3FsInputStream.read(NativeS3FileSystem.java:313)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.moveToNext(MapTask.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.next(MapTask.java:185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)

Error: java.io.IOException: Unexpected end of stream pos=291259038 contentLength= 458603265
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem$NativeS3FsInputStream.read(NativeS3FileSystem.java:313)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.moveToNext(MapTask.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.next(MapTask.java:185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)

Error: java.io.IOException: Unexpected end of stream pos=222629174 contentLength= 458603265
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem$NativeS3FsInputStream.read(NativeS3FileSystem.java:313)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.moveToNext(MapTask.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.next(MapTask.java:185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)

Error: java.io.IOException: Unexpected end of stream pos=155898310 contentLength= 458603265
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem$NativeS3FsInputStream.read(NativeS3FileSystem.java:313)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.moveToNext(MapTask.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.next(MapTask.java:185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)

Error: java.io.IOException: Unexpected end of stream pos=88645447 contentLength= 458603265
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem$NativeS3FsInputStream.read(NativeS3FileSystem.java:313)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.moveToNext(MapTask.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.next(MapTask.java:185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)
```

I had runa another job with similar config and it had worked fine.Any inputs?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue with spark + hive.  The issue was that I issued a hive query to write to a location in s3, backed by a dataframe, then immediately reading from it.  Something like:

```
statusDF.createOrReplaceTempView("statusDF")
spark.sql(s"INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE ${table} SELECT id, last_updated FROM statusDF")
statusDF.show(5)
```

So one possibility is that you're doing a read in the middle of something else writing to the same S3 location (but is not yet finished), which is producing this error.